# Doubt related to multiplicity of eigenvalue with $\operatorname{rank} A =r<n$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If $A $ is a matrix of order $n $ and $Ax=\lambda x$ for some non zero $x$, where  $\lambda  $  is a real number then $(x,\lambda)$ is eigenpairs.

I am curious about this statement.

**Doubt:** If $A $ is a matrix of order $n$ with $ \operatorname{rank} (A)=r <n$ $Ax=\lambda x$,  $\forall$ non zero $ x \in \mathbb{R}^r$, where  $\lambda  $  is a real number then can we conclude about the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda $ from here?

Edit: My Guess, In this case,  $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $r$ and the corresponding eigenvector $x$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does "$\forall 0\neq x$ means $\forall x \neq 0$? (I can't understand what $\forall 0$ can mean) If yes, then your statement is equivalent to just $\forall x: Ax = \lambda x$. From this you can find $A$ explicitly, including multiplicity of $\lambda$.

Comment: A better (more speicifc) title would be *What is the multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ if $Ax=\lambda x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n,x\neq 0$?*.

Comment: Thank you, But I have just edited the question actually that is my confusion

Comment: Is this a question or exercise from somewhere, or a question you've come up with yourself? The assumption that $\mathrm{rank}(A) < n$ is a bit odd - (it somewhat trivialises the question, actually.) Can you say a little about why you're curious about this statement and how far you've got in trying to answer your question? What's your definition of "multiplicity of an eigenvalue", what theorems about multiplicities do you know, and how might you apply them?

Comment: Can you write out the elements of $A$, given $\lambda$? As already mentioned, they're completely determined by the condition $\forall x\neq 0:Ax=\lambda x$.

Comment: You got $m(0)=n-r$ simply with rank thm